# How to copy an array of characters to a string C++

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I am writing a function that takes in a string through pass by reference and an array of characters and the size of the array. The string already has characters in it. I am trying to erase the characters in the string and copy the characters from the array.
I tried setting up a for loop to copy, but it doesn't work if the string is too small or too big. I can't use strcopy in this function. Need some guidance.

```
void functionname(string &first, char arr[], int size) {

int i;

    (for i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    first[i] = arr[i];
    }

}
```

Comment: What doesn't work about it? Are you getting errors? What are they?

Comment: FWIW, you code isn't reliable when the incoming value of `first` has `.size()` less than the `size` argument.  Say `first` is "abc", `arr[]` is VWXYZ and size is 5... you copy `VWX` over `abc` - which is allowed - but then try to copy `Z` over the `first[4]` which is (as of C++11) guaranteed to hold a NUL but isn't legal to write to (for C++03 it may not be a NUL and is also undefined behaviour to write), then of course writing the final `Z` is beyond even any possible NUL and even in C++11 the indexing operation is undefined behaviour, let alone the write....

Answer (score 2):

You can use `std::string`'s default assignment operator `=` and simply do

```
first = arr;
```

Comment: just a note: this works if `arr` holds ASCIIZ text (i.e. textual character terminated by a NUL/0 character that you don't consider part of the text/value), while zzz777's answer happily sets the string to contain the first `size` characters from the array *even if* some/all are NUL.

Answer (score 2):

std::string has function to do it first.assign(arr, size)

Answer (score 1):

The below works as std::string overrides the assignment operator (=) for char* to allow direct assignment to the string from a character pointer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

void functionname(string &first, char arr[], int size) 
{
    first = arr;
}

int main()
{
    std::string x = "mystring";
    char buff[x.length()];
    strcpy(buff, "other");

    cout << x << endl;
    functionname(x, buff, x.length());

    cout << x << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`string` has a constructor that copies a character array and takes a count. This will work no matter what contents are inside the `arr` array, even embedded null characters.

```
void functionname(string &first, char arr[], int size) {

    first = string(arr, size);

}
```

Again, the contents of `arr` are copied into the string, you don't need to keep `arr` around after this if you don't need it anymore.